# Service compiling successfully, but message structs not generating - gRPC/Go

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go, protobuf-go

I am using gRPC/protobufs as the protocol to communicate between my client and server, both written in go. I'm able to run the command show below to generate the `cards.pb.go` (server) and `cards_grpc.pb.go` (client) files without any problem. The server file is working perfectly, without any issues. The client file, however, does not seem to have access to the `message` items that I have defined within my `cards.proto` file. My services, as well as my client code, require the defined message struct in order to call the service methods, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here is the command I'm running:

```
protoc -I="./protos" \
--go_out=plugins=grpc:./server \
--go-grpc_out=./client \
protos/*.proto
```

Here is my project file structure:

```
|-- client
    |-- protos (generated protobufs for client)
        |-- cards_grpc.pb.go (this compiled successfully, but structs representing my messages cannot be found)
|-- protos (This is where the proto files are defined)
    |-- cards.proto
|-- server
    |-- protos (generated protobufs for server)
        |-- cards.pb.go (this is working perfectly, has compiled services and messages)
```

**Note:** I have defined `option go_package = "./protos";` in my `cards.proto` file, which is why the generated files have outputted into `*/protos/*.pb.go` locations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are not generating any protobuf related code for the client code here, only gRPC one. In order to generate the structure that you are looking for, use the following command:

```
protoc -I./protos        \
  --go_out=./server      \
  --go-grpc_out=./server \
  --go_out=./client      \
  --go-grpc_out=./client \
  protos/*.proto
```

The `--go_out` generates the go code for protobuf and the `--go-grpc_out` generates the go code for gRPC.

Another thing, `--go_out=plugins=grpc` [are not supported in go anymore](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/1070). You should use the `--go-grpc_out`.

## More recommendations

I highly recommend to share the proto directory with both the client and the server (if possible), this limits the potential error due to unsynchronised Proto files.

So you would have something like:

```
|-- client
|-- protos
    |-- cards.proto
    |-- cards_grpc.pb.go
    |-- cards.pb.go
|-- server
```

and then both access the files needed.

Second, if you are working with Go modules, I recommend that you use the `go_package` as following:

```
option go_package = "${YOUR_MODULE}/protos"
```

and then generate the code like this:

```
protoc -Iprotos \
  --go_opt=module=${YOUR_MODULE} --go_out=. \
  --go-grpc_opt=module=${YOUR_MODULE} --go-grpc_out=. \
  protos/*.proto
```

Notice the `.` for the `--go_out` and `--go-grpc_out`. This maps the root of your project to the module name and this will generate the code inside your `protos` directory by removing the Module name to the `go_package` option. Then you will be able to access this generated code in your code like so:

```golang
import (
    pb "${YOUR_MODULE}/protos"
)
```

## Clarification

Just to be clear about the `go_package`, you need to understand one thing: the protobuf package and the `go_package` are not the same thing, the former defines package only usable in .proto files, the latter defines the `package ...` inside your go files. An example:

### For Protobuf package

#### file1.proto

```proto
//...
package protos;

message Test {}
//...
```

#### file2.proto

```proto
//...
//no package definition

message Test2 {
    protos.Test a_test = 1;
}
//...
```

### For `go_package`

#### go.mod

```
module my_module
```

#### file1.proto (at location: ${ROOT}/protos)

```proto
//...
option go_package = "my_module/protos"

message Test {}
//...
```

#### generation

```
protoc -I./protos        \
  --go_out=./server      \
  --go-grpc_out=./server \
  --go_out=./client      \
  --go-grpc_out=./client \
  protos/file1.proto
```

#### main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    pb "my_module/proto"
)

func main() {
    var test pb.Test;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - the issue is my project is using GCP Cloud Functions, so I can't share protos between the server and client (Cloud Function). I have a very simple bash file that hopefully addresses the issue of inconsistent which is where these commands are located, not perfect, but if you know of any better way to handle it, that would be great.

Additionally - in the first portion, it looks like the commands you have added are the same as the one I'm using, at least for the client?

Comment: Also - I'm still not understanding what exactly `go_package` in this context does - I have my module definition in the `go.mod` (let's say `my_module`) - why does my `protos` package need to be defined as `my_package/protos` instead of just 'protos`? Shouldn't this be importable with just the latter?

Comment: @Sal so first I edited the generation command, I was explaining that you generate only gRPC code for the client but I didn't provide the right solution, the first command should do the trick now

Comment: Added some explanation, you might want to reread the whole thing since I added few details. Let me know how I can further help.